# How to get parent id from nested id which equals (params[:id])?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I list all the `duels` a `challenge` has on the challenge show page?

A challenge doesn't have a `duel_id`, but a `dueler` has a `challenge_id`.

**challenges_controller**

```
def show
 @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:id])
 @correct_user = current_user.challenges.find_by(id: params[:id])
 @duel = # How to get any and all duels which have a dueler whose challenge_id is equal to @challenge?
end
```

**challenges/show.html.erb**

```
<% @duel.duelers.each do |dueler| %> # Two duelers per duel. I want to show both duelers on page.
  <%= dueler.user.name %> will <%= dueler.challenge.name %>.
<% end %>
<%= @challenge.name %>
```

**rails c**

```
Duel.last
 id: 169,
pry(main)> Dueler.last
 id: 276,
 user_id: 2,
 challenge_id: 301,
 duel_id: 169,
```

Comment: What is the relation between `challenge`, `duel` and `dueler`

Comment: I thought `rails c` shows that relationship? duels has_many duelers. challenge has_many duels & duelers, but I don't know if that has much of any effect since their is no column in the DB for it @RSB

Comment: If `challenge` has_many `duels` than `duel` must be having `challenge_id` right?

Comment: You can add a `has_many :duels, through: :duelers` relation in the Challenge class, it performs a join with duelers and duels where the challenge id is the requested. The you can get the duels by typing `@challenge.duels`

Comment: No @RSB I said "A challenge doesn't have a `duel_id`"

Comment: I did as you said @Rendrum, but I get error `undefined method 'duelers'` for `#<Duel::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fc6cf313380>` from line `<% @duel.duelers.each do |dueler| %>`

Comment: Try adding a has_many :duelers In the Duel class.

Comment: It is there @Rendrum

Comment: Your classes should look like this:
`class Challenge
  has_many :duelers
  has_many :duels,  through: :duelers
end
class Dueler
  belongs_to :duel
  belongs_to :challenge
end
class Duel
  has_many :duelers
end`

Comment: Yes that's what I have @Rendrum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `duels` table doesn't have `challenge_id`, you can do this to get duels through duelers.

```
def show
 @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:id])
 @correct_user = current_user.challenges.find_by(id: params[:id])
 @duel = Duel.where(id: @challenge.duelers.pluck(:duel_id).uniq).includes(duelers: :user)
end
```

And, don't forget to add `has_many :duelers` in `duel` model.

Since there can be multiple `duels` for a challenge, you need to make this change in your view

```
<% @duel.each do |duel| %>
  <% duel.duelers.each do |dueler| %> # Two duelers per duel. I want to show both duelers on page.
    <%= dueler.user.name %> will <%= @challenge.name %>.
  <% end %>
  <%= @challenge.name %>
<% end %>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I get error `undefined method 'duelers'` for `#<Duel::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fc6cf‌​313380> from line <% @duel.duelers.each do |dueler| %>`

Comment: Is there a possibility of having multiple `duels` for a challenge?

Comment: Yes sir. I've only tested with one duel so far for the challenge

Comment: If yes, then check my edit, you need to do those chanegs in the view.

Comment: Ah good call with the `view`, but `@duel` is still providing error `undefined method 'duelers' for #<Duel::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fc6cd049110>`

Comment: @RSB this query ` Duel.where(id: @challenge.duelers.pluck(:duel_id).uniq).includes(:duelers)` performs two hits to the database. Try using select instead of pluck, so it generates a subquery :) So it should be:  `Duel.where(id: @challenge.duelers.select(:duel_id).uniq).includes(:duelers)`

Comment: Same thing with your edit `undefined method 'duelers' for #<Duel::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fc6caf58d48>`. Btw if I put `Duel.last` the error goes away just to give you an idea that the problem does lie with the line you are working on.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Check my edit, its `duel.duelers.each` not `@duel.duelers.each`

Comment: @Rendrum `select` will not return an array of ids. It will return array of objects.

Comment: @RSB Yes, but you don't need and don't want it :) If you use select, you will get only one query that will return the same results.

Comment: Ah true I was putting it in the wrong view. The error went away :) But now `duel` looks to be iterating like 100+ times.

Comment: Why do you need duel at all if you just want to iterate all the duelers?

Comment: There are attributes to `duel` that I want to include (not shown in question)

Comment: Cool! So are you facing any kind of problem in the above solution?

Comment: What about `@duelers = Dueler.where(challenge: @challenge).includes(:duel)`  then iterate with `@dueleres` ?

Comment: @Rendrum That's what I asked him, he might need to `order` the `duelers` by `duel_id` to avoid `duelers` appearing in random order in the view.

Comment: Also iterates like 100 times @Rendrum

Comment: But as RSB wrote in the answer it could be because of `dueler.user.name` and `dueler.challenge.name`, try `@duelers = Dueler.where(challenge: @challenge).includes(:duel, :user, :challenge)`

Comment: Same deal @Rendrum

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com :( Check the log of SQL to identify where the database is being hit in the 100+ times query and try this `@duelers = Dueler.includes(:duel, :user, :challenge).where(challenge: @challenge)`

Comment: I don't know where 100+ queries are running, I have done the joins here `Duel.where(id: @challenge.duelers.pluck(:duel_id).uniq).includes(duelers: :user)`

Comment: Instead of `dueler.challenge.name` you can just use `@challenge.name` since its on the show page of `@challenge` only.

Comment: Actually you're right. The queires were a mistake I was making elsewhere. I fixed :) Now with that said, the one dueler is shown but I want to show both duelers from the duel. If you feel me @Rendrum

Comment: That query is not good. In your controller, place this variable: `@duelers = Dueler.includes(:duel, :user, :challenge).where(challenge: @challenge)` then use it in your view `<% @duelers.each do |dueler| %>`

Comment: @Rendrum I don't thnk there's a need of including `challenge` there because we already have it in `@challenge`. We can just use that there.

Comment: @Rendrum gave me a nil answer on your last comment. R3B's answer worked perfectly :) Thank you both for walking with me on this one and helping to clarify the problem and solution. Much love!